# Amplify a signal and phase shift it by multiplying by a complex number

Tags: phase, amplitude, complex

Still need help 25th October 2019

I have a real time domain signal contained in an array, it's just two different frequencies summed together. If I want to amplify this signal by 10 and phase modulate it by 0.5 degrees, will this work?

1. Change the real signal to a complex signal. $ (e^{\omega_1t} + e^{\omega_2t})$
2. Multiply it by the phasor $Ae^{i \theta}$
3. So the calculation is $Ae^{i \theta} (e^{\omega_1t} + e^{\omega_2t})$
4. Where $A=10$ is an amplitude change and $\theta=0.5 \pi/180$ is the phase change caused by the equipment
5. Take the real signal of this calculation to get the result

The numbers I have used, 10 and 0.5, are just an example.

Please can someone share knowledge please?

Comment: What is phase shift in time domain? Is not simply delay?

Comment: It's a phase modulation that I am doing

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_modulation what does it say? You modulate message, generally message means a very specifc and time domain signal a broad meaning.

Comment: I am unsure what you mean

Comment: @NatalieJohnson Please clarify, using equations if possible, what is the meaning of "phase modulate it by 0.5 degrees". That is not a term with a well-known definition in communications.

Comment: @NatalieJohnson both your approaches are wrong, but mainly due to the fact that you want to phase-shift a real-valued signal, but then expect it to still be real-valued – and it won't be!

Comment: @MarcusMüller  Hi. I think I know the solution, I have been experimenting over night and I think I just need to make this input signal complex then do a complex modulation on it (method 1 above). Since I am creating the signal to start with, I just add i*sin to it, then after using 10*exp(i*0.5*(pi/180)) it appears to be right if I take the real version of the new_signal. The result looks like I have a phase shift of 0.5 degrees and amplitude increase of 10.

Comment: "real" is just a special case of "complex"; don't do anything to your input signal; just omit the "taking the real part".

Comment: @MarcusMüller MBaz   Lost what your implying I should change. I take the real part after I change my real signal to a complex signal and also after I have multiplied it by a complex modulating phasor that only has a Amplitude and phase adjustment.

Comment: don't take the real part. Your signal is now complex.

Comment: @MarcusMüller MBaz  How would I plot what the actual signal is like in the real world? All this is meant to do is amplify and then do a small phase shift to a real signal, I must have real signal at the end?

Comment: @NatalieJohnson ok, I think we need to talk about bandpass signals and equivalent baseband signals. Are you aware of the latter?

Comment: @MarcusMüller  Yes. The baseband raw data of a signal prior to being multiplied by the carrier. This baseband data is in the time domain and has an unacceptable large frequency spectrum. We pass it through a square root raised cosine filter prior to mixing with a carrier.

Comment: very well, so you'd need to phase shift that; why shift the passband signal after mixing?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Its an unwanted modulation caused by an equipment. It has nothing to do with the data, its purely acting on any signal. My signal happens to be a sum of sine waves. I think turning this signal into a complex signal then multiplying it by Ae^(i*theta) where A is the amplitude and theta is phase change of the equipment. It appears to work if I take the real part of this new signal, but you say no? result looks okay...

Comment: Ok, now we **really** need you to define what phase modulation means to you, in mathematical terms; having your signal model is great, by the way! All the info you're giving here in the comments should be worked into your question, so that a potential answerer doesn't have to read all our discussion here.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Done, hope I have been clearer?

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain the first bit in slightly more detail? Where do the $\omega_i$ come from?

Comment: @MarcusMüller its just two sine waves added together. such as f=10 and f=11. My signal that i am using doesnt have to be just two, it can be any number of sine waves added together.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying by a complex number causes a rescaling by the magnitude and a rotation by the angle.  This is why when you multiply two complex numbers, you multiply the magnitudes and add the angles.

The only signal for which a complex multiplication (rescale and rotation) is the equivalent of a phase shift is a single complex pure tone (looks like a spring, or threads on a bolt).  The frequency is the translation value between the rotation amount and the shift size in the time domain.  Thus if you have a signal that is a sum of complex pure tones with different frequencies, each will be shifted by a different amount by the same non-real multiplication factor, and the sum of the shifted tones will not match a shift of the sum.

Since a real pure tone is the sum of two complex pure tones of different frequencies, it cannot be shifted by a complex scalar multiplication, nor can any sum of them.

That's all there is to it.

Comment: Hi, Yes I was testing on single frequency. Doesnt work for multiple frequencies. Do you know what would work?

Comment: @NatalieJohnson To add to Cedron's good answer- time delay is the negative derivative of phase with respect to frequency. So if you have a linearly decreasing phase as you increase frequency, the result will be a constant delay in time at all frequencies (hence the benefit of linear phase filters).